# ng-switch not switching as expected

Tags: angularjs

I seem to be missing something basic here for `ng-switch`. Here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/63jvcb7v/).

I'm trying to switch on `profile_type` but am unable to.

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="result in results">
        <div ng-switch="profile_type">
            <div ng-switch-when="PatientProfile">{{ result.name }}</div>
            <div ng-switch-when="DoctorProfile">{{ result.name }}</div>
        </div>
    </div
</div>

$scope.results = [
    {profile_type: "PatientProfile", name: "Steve Patient"},
    {profile_type: "DoctorProfile", name: "Joe Doctor"},
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something is missing, find this line and change it like this:

```
<div ng-switch="result.profile_type">
```